# Is it possible to display data in thymeleaf without that data present in database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table `user` and table `wallets`. User can have as many wallets as he wants.

They are connected with IDs. Now, I made a service that sum balance of all user wallets.

So if user with ID 1 have a wallet with:

`Wallet`

```
id:1
balance: 100
userId: 1

id:2
balance: 200
userId: 1
```

His total balance will be `300`, so I want to display that data.

This is method to find all wallets that one user hold, and sum total balance of them:

```
  @Override
  public void netWorth(Long userId) {
    List<Wallet> wallets = walletRepository.findDistinctIdByUserId(userId);
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wallets.size(); i++)
        sum += wallets.get(i).getInitialBalance();
}
```

But how I can display that data on thymeleaf?

This is how I display balance of each wallet with controller and thymeleaf:

```
@GetMapping("/userWallet/balance/{user_id}")
public String getUserWallet(@PathVariable(value = "user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wallet", walletService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    return "user_profile";
}
```

And in thymeleaf:

```
<div th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
<div class="wallet">
    <p th:text="${wallet.walletName}"></p>
    <p th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"></p>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

But how I can achieve to display total balance of all wallets? Do I need to create a new column `totalBalance` and to set on it balance from my method? Any advice?

Comment: Total Balance would be a calculated field (either by adding up all your rows in code or by a query to the database, perhaps a separate query)  You then add `totalBalance` to your Controller's model and then display that value like any of the other values in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all of your data to your thymeleaf.Consider that the sum of all wallets are in a variable named `totalWallets`.

```
@GetMapping("/userWallet/balance/{user_id}")
public String getUserWallet(@PathVariable(value = "user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wallet", walletService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    //get wallet sum. e.g. getWalletSum();
    var totalWallet = getWalletSum();
    model.addAttribute("totalWallets", totalWallets);
    return "user_profile";
}
```

now, you can show it in your view.

```
<div th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
<div class="wallet">
    <p th:text="${wallet.walletName}"></p>
    <p th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div th:text="${totalWallets}"></div>
</div>
```